# JPA entity from a table with non-unique id

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, dictionary, orm

I want to have an entity

```
class InkFormula {
    int id;
    Map<Ink, Integer> inkPercents;        
    ...
}
```

from a single table with such a structure:

```
┌─────┬────────┬─────────┐
│ id  │ ink_id │ percent │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│  1  │   1    │   50    │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│  1  │   2    │   25    │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│  1  │   3    │   0     │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│  2  │   1    │   100   │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│  2  │   2    │   80    │
└─────┴────────┴─────────┘
```

where non-unique `id` must be used to congregate a `Map<>` from `ink_id` and `percent`.

The reason why I need a single entity and a single table is a requirement to have unique constraint `id`, `ink_id` so that each formula could not contain repeated inks.

Is that possible with JPA and Hibernate?

Comment: and what maps on to "percent" ?

Comment: Map<Ink, Integer> must be mapped from "ink_id" (int) and "percent" (int)

Comment: you mean this is a JoinTable?

Comment: Neil, it is not. I need to have exactly this single table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution could be using an `@ElementCollection` annotation and separating data into two tables:

```
ink_formula    ink_formula_ink_percent
  ┌───┐    ┌──────────────┬──────┬───────┐
  │id │    │ink_formula_id│ink_id│percent│
  ├───┤    ├──────────────┼──────┼───────┤
  │ 1 │    │       1      │   1  │   20  │
  ├───┤    ├──────────────┼──────┼───────┤
  │ 2 │    │       1      │   2  │   55  │
  ├───┤    ├──────────────┼──────┼───────┤
  . . .    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

The entity class will then look like

```
@Entity
public class InkFormula {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;      

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name="ink_formula_ink_percent",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ink_formula_id")
    )
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="ink_id")
    @Column(name = "percent")
    private Map<Ink, Integer> inkPercents = new TreeMap<>();

    //...    
}
```

This setup satisfies the unique `InkFormula-Ink` requirement but we need a separate table for `InkFormula`.

Next question is how to ensure the uniqueness of each `InkFormula` since two `InkFormulas` with different `id`s can hold the same values in their `inkPercents` maps.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a composite primary key `InkFormulaId` which contains two fields: `id` and `ink_id` similar to

```
@Embeddable
public class InkFormulaId implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;

    private Integer inkId;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class InkFormula {

    @EmbeddedId
    private InkFormulaId inkFormulaId;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId(value = "inkId")
    private Ink ink;

    private Integer percents;

    // ...
}
```

so each `InkFormula` represents a single line in your table above with a unique primary key (`id`, `inkId`) and their `percents`.

To get the mapping you mentioned above, you would have to `SELECT` all `InkFormula` for a single `id` and then group them by `inkId` in your Java code.

Comment: What I want to have is an `InkFormula` entity from all rows with the same `id`, not for each row. That's a challenge.

Comment: That's not possible as having multiple values for a single row would break the "A" in "ACID" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and each JPA entity represents a single row.

Comment: OK, we can put `InkFormula`'s `id` into a separate `ink_formula` table. Then let this table be called `ink_formula_percent`. But still the question remains: how to join `ink_formula` and `ink_formula_percent` into a single entity.

Comment: Why another table - have you tried my example above? It leads to a single table and all that you manually have to do is just to group the `InkFormula` objects first by `id` and then by `inkId`.

Comment: Thanks, Smutje, I tried it – it works fine. But I am too lazy to group the `Map<>` manually. I'd like to have it done by Hibernate and the database. Or maybe I don't get how to do this without too much work? See my alternative solution bellow.

Comment: You could extend your `Ink` entity by a `@OneToMany` list of `InkFormula` and then group the `InkFormula` during a `@EntityListener` so that each `Ink` entity gets the map populated on load.

Comment: `Ink` is an immutable class that we don't want to extend. When constructing new `InkFormula` we just reference `Ink` used for the formula and specify it's percent. For example there are Cyan and Magenta inks. A formula can contain 100% of Cyan + 20% of Magenta. `Map<Ink, Integer> inkPercents = new TreeMap<Ink, Integer>(){{
put(Ink.CYAN, 100);
put(Ink.MAGENTA, 20);
}};`

Comment: I will think of using `@EntityListener` anyway.